# Salesforce:Add record to a field which is dependent on the input of other field

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have an object named 'Salary'. There are three fields in it- 'Add Salary', 'Month' and 'Available Salary'. Also there is a lookup relationship from Salary object to 'User Name' object. For every user  there is a salary record for every month. Whenever salary is added to a particular user's record, the available salary should show the sum of salaries of previous months. How can I do that?? Please suggest me....Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the Lookup Relationship to a Master-Detail Relationship and use a [Roll-Up Summary](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm) field on the User object (Setup > Customize > Users > Fields > User Custom Fields > New).

Alternatively, you could use a [Trigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_triggers_defining.htm) on the Salary object, but only do that if you absolutely need additional functionality that cannot be accomplished with a Roll-Up Summary or other configuration.

Here's an example of using a Trigger. I haven't tried compiling it, so there will inevitably be some compile errors, but it's a place to start.

```
trigger AddSalary on Salary__c (after update) {

    // create a set of all the unique User Ids
    Map<Id,List<Salary__c>> SalaryByUserId = new Map<Id,List<Salary__c>>();
    for(Salary__c s : Trigger.new)
    {
        List<Salary__c> SalariesForUser = SalaryByUserId.get(s.User__c);

        if(SalariesForUser == null) 
        { 
            SalaryByUserId.put(s.User__c,new Salary__c[]{s}); 
        }
        else
        {
            SalariesForUser.add(s);
            SalaryByUserId.put(s.User__c,SalariesForUser); 
        }
    }

    // query for all the User records for the unique UserIds in the records
    // create a map for a lookup / hash table for the User info
    Map<Id,User> Users = new Map<Id,User>(
        [Select Id, Username, Available_Salary__c From User Where Id IN SalaryByUserId.keyset()]);

    // iterate over the list of records being processed in the Trigger and add the Salaries to the Users
    for (Id i : SalaryByUserId.keyset())
    {
        User u = Users.get(i);
        Decimal TotalSalary = 0;

        for(Salary__c s : SalaryByUserId.get(u.Id))
        {
            TotalSalary += s.Monthly_Salary__c;
        }

        Users.get(u.Id).Total_Salary__c = TotalSalary;
    }

    update Users;

}
```

Comment: How can i use roll-up summary field?? It only works if there is a master detail relationship b/w two objects. In trigger, if i initialize the available_salary__c field with zero, it is getting equal to zero everytime a new record is created. So, I am not able to add the salaries of previous months. Please tell me how to proceed.    Thanks

Comment: Why not change the Lookup to a Master-Detail relationship?

Comment: I can't make it a Master-detail since there are other functionalities too in my application. Can i do anything else if i have only lookup relationship b/w the objects??